# username with `james i. adams` not accepted with django routers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets, drf-nested-routers

I have registered routers for `user` model, which has viewset that has lookup_url as `username`.
The username `james adams` is accepted by the router, but getting below error for `james i. adams`

```py
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'user-detail' with keyword arguments '{'username': 'james i. adam', 'version': 'v1'}' not found. 4 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<version>(v4))/users/(?P<username>[^/.]+)/?\\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$', '(?P<version>(v4))/users/(?P<username>[^/.]+)/?$', '(?P<version>(v1))/users/(?P<username>[^/.]+)/?\\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$', '(?P<version>(v1))/users/(?P<username>[^/.]+)/?$']
```

Can someone guide me, how can I allow such username for url patterns with routers registered?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I see you do have an answer, but more standard practice might be to generate a unique slug for the record and use that in the URL instead of the actual username. If you look at the SO URL for this question, that's exactly what they are doing there ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see, the default regex for [URL values *excludes `.`*](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter):

```
/users/(?P<username>[^/.]+)/
                       ^
```

You will have to change that regex; if you're using viewsets, that's as easy as:

```
class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    lookup_value_regex = '[^/]+'
```

Comment: Thanks alot ! It worked :) Just want to know if you know any specific reason why by default they don't allow `.` character? Is it coz it might be security vulnerable or lead to some invalid url?

Comment: Probably because it accepts `.json`, `.xml` etc. in the URL to switch to different return formats.

Comment: okay thank you :)